# Write list of bytes into a file, but some records got lost

Tags: python, byte

I am new to programming and got an issue with writing bytes. Here is what I wrote:

```
file = open('filePath/input.train', 'wb')
for i in range(len(myList)):
    file.write(bytes((myList[i]),'UTF-8'));
```

If I print 'i' here, it is 629.

The '.train' suffix is required by the project. In order to check it, I read it and write to a txt file:

```
file = open('filePath/input.train', 'rb')
content = file.read()
testFile = open('filePath/test.txt', 'wb')
testFile.write(content)
```

Now, the problem is, len(list) = 629 while I got 591 lines in test.txt file. It brought me problems later.

Why did this happen and how should I solve it?

Comment: you missed the 'b' in your second and third `open` statements. if you are working with binary files make sure to open them as binary(which is what 'rb' and 'wb' mean)

Comment: I tried this just now. Same result. I have updated my post. Anything else I can try with? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, when you open and write a file, need remember close the file after the write.like this.

```
file = open('filePath/input.train', 'wb')
for i in range(len(myList)):
    file.write(bytes((myList[i]),'UTF-8'));
file.close()
```

second, python code not must has ";"

third, `file` is python's keyword, so don't use `file` be your variable name. you can use `f` or `my_file` or anyone, but don't use python's keyword.

fourth, python has a `iterator`,  use `iterator` is better than your `for i in range(len(xxx))`.

all of this, your code can look like this.

```
f = open('filePath/input.train', 'wb')
for line in myList:
    f.write(bytes(line, 'UTF-8'))
f.close()
```

Comment: Yes! It was the file.close(). Thank you soooooo much!!! I am new here and trying to figure out how to select yours as answer.